# Storing and accessing values after each iteration in a random network in R

Tags: r, networking, graph, dataframe, igraph

I have created a random (Erdos-Renyi) network using R (and the igraph package), that has 10 nodes. Each node has been randomly assigned with an attribute of either 0 or 1.

I have applied the simple majority rule on these nodes so that if the majority of a node's neighbors have the attribute of 0, then the node's attribute changes to 0 as well (or 1 if the majority have 1). It goes through all of the nodes in the network iteratively, according to their numbers (1-10), and applies the simple majority rule.

Here is my code to create the graph:

```
# Creates an Erdos-Renyi graph with 10 nodes and edges with p=0.2
num_nodes <- 10
prob <- 0.2
graph <- erdos.renyi.game(num_nodes, prob, type=c("gnp", "gnm"), directed=FALSE, 
    loops=FALSE)

# Randomly sets the attributes of the nodes to either 0 or 1
graph <- set.vertex.attribute(graph, "value", value = sample(0:1, num_nodes, 
    replace=TRUE))
```

Here is my code to apply the simple majority rule that I have so far:

```
modified <- FALSE
iterations <- 0 #keeps track of how many iterations take place
for (i in 1:num_nodes*10) {
    modified = FALSE
    iterations <- iterations + 1
    for (i in 1:num_nodes) {
        adj_ones <- 0 #keeps track of how many neighbors of a node have 1s
        adj_zeros <- 0 #keeps track of how many neighbors of a node have 0s
        for (j in neighbors(graph, i)) { #looks at the neighbors of a node
            if (get.vertex.attribute(graph, "value", index = j) == 1) {
                adj_ones <- adj_ones + 1 #increments one count if neighbor is 1
            } else {
                adj_zeros <- adj_zeros + 1 # or increments zero count if 
                                                          #neighbor is 0
            }
        }
        modified = FALSE
        #I need to modify this bit so that the 0 or 1 changes are only stored 
        #rather than actually changed
        if (adj_ones > adj_zeros) { #updates 0 or 1 value of node
            if (V(graph)$value[which(V(graph)==i)] == 0) {
                modified = TRUE
                V(graph)$value[which(V(graph)==i)] = 1
            }
        } else if (adj_ones < adj_zeros) {
            if (V(graph)$value[which(V(graph)==i)] == 1) {
                modified = TRUE
                V(graph)$value[which(V(graph)==i)] = 0
            }
        }
    if (!modified) {
        break
    }
}
```

It all works fine, but I need to modify it so that after it looks at a node, and if this node's 0 or 1 value needs to be changed, instead of changing it, it stores the new value instead. So that when the neighbors of this node are being checked, they use the node's original value rather than it's changed (stored) value. The stored value of each node needs to be updated as required after each iteration of all of the nodes. (i.e. the 2nd iteration of all the nodes' values uses the 1st iteration's values of the nodes, and the 3rd iteration uses the 2nd iteration's values).

I'm not too sure how to go about doing this. Would I need to store the updated values in a data frame and access them for each iteration using this? How would I go about doing this? Or is there a different way to do it?

Comment: I personally think that the igraph package is overkill for this. If you have a network with <100 vertices, just use a dense adjacency matrix, and a vector to store the attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @GaborCsardi, but I need to do other things with the graph as well, and the igraph package seems to be the best way to do them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a second variable for each node (let's call it "flip"), which is set if the node needs to flip because the majority of its neighbors differ. In the first pass of each iteration, you flag all the nodes that need to flip. In the second pass, you actually update all the values.

Here is some code that I think should do the trick (based largely off the code you posted):

```
library(igraph)

# Creates an Erdos-Renyi graph with 10 nodes and edges with p=0.2
num_nodes <- 10
prob <- 0.2
graph <- erdos.renyi.game(num_nodes, prob, type=c("gnp", "gnm"), directed=FALSE, 
    loops=FALSE)

# Randomly sets the attributes of the nodes to either 0 or 1
graph <- set.vertex.attribute(graph, "value", value = sample(0:1, num_nodes, 
    replace=TRUE))

modified <- FALSE
iterations <- 0 #keeps track of how many iterations take place
for (i in 1:num_nodes*10) {
    # Initially set flip to all false
    graph <- set.vertex.attribute(graph, "flip", value=rep(FALSE, num_nodes))

    modified = FALSE
    iterations <- iterations + 1
    for (i in 1:num_nodes) {
        adj_ones <- 0 #keeps track of how many neighbors of a node have 1s
        adj_zeros <- 0 #keeps track of how many neighbors of a node have 0s
        for (j in neighbors(graph, i)) { #looks at the neighbors of a node
            if (get.vertex.attribute(graph, "value", index = j) == 1) {
                adj_ones <- adj_ones + 1 #increments one count if neighbor is 1
            } else {
                adj_zeros <- adj_zeros + 1 # or increments zero count if 
                                                          #neighbor is 0
            }
        }
        modified = FALSE
        #I need to modify this bit so that the 0 or 1 changes are only stored 
        #rather than actually changed
        i.pos = which(V(graph) == i)
        if (adj_ones > adj_zeros) { #updates 0 or 1 value of node
            if (V(graph)$value[i.pos] == 0) {
                modified = TRUE
                V(graph)$flip[i.pos] = TRUE
            }
        } else if (adj_ones < adj_zeros) {
            if (V(graph)$value[which(V(graph)==i)] == 1) {
                modified = TRUE
            V(graph)$flip[i.pos] = TRUE
            }
        }
    }
    if (!modified) {
        break
    }

    # Actually flip the things we labeled as needing to flip
    for (i in 1:num_nodes) {
           if (V(graph)$flip[i]) {
               V(graph)$value[i] = 1-V(graph)$value[i]
           }
    }
}
```